# How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser, https, mixed-content

Chrome browser by default is blocking mixed content. How do I adjust my settings/configuration to allow mixed content without making any adjustments on the UI every time?

I have found two solutions but neither of them work:

1. Several articles say you can adjust this under the Security section
   of "Under the Hood" in the Options. This option no longer seems to
   exist. There is no Under The Hood tab and there is no such dropdown
   to adjust how Chrome handles mixed content as far as I can tell.
2. Another option is to add the `--allow-running-insecure-content` flag
   to your command line. I did this like so:  `"C:\Program
   Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
   --allow-running-insecure-content`.  However this made no difference. If I tried adding the flag inside the double quotes, then Windows
   complains saying it is invalid.

So what option do I have now with the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: @StevenV I can think of may scenarios when I might want or need to "defeat" this behavior. but that's not really the question. The op wants to know HOW to do it. If you don't know, then why bother commenting? op - Your #1 works for me on a https site that references non-https images for example. Although this isn't a programming question and shouldn't be on SO. Post it on SuperUser instead.

Comment: So you have a Under the Hood section of your Chrome settings? I dont!

Comment: This worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480814/996926

Comment: nothing from the answers below worked for me, so I ended up using Firefox where you still can be "unsafe" (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox#w_unblock-mixed-content)

Answer (score 289):

**Steps as of Chrome v91 (6/17/2021):**

1. Click the **Not secure** warning next to the URL

[image]

2. Click Site settings on the popup box

[image]

3. Near the bottom of the list is **Insecure content**, change this to **Allow**

[image]

4. Close settings, go back to the site, and Refresh the page

---

**Older Chrome Versions:**

timmmy_42 answers this on: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OrwppKWbKnc

> In the address bar at the right end should be a 'shield' icon, you can
> click on that to run insecure content.

This worked for me in Chromium-dev Version 36.0.1933.0 (262849).

Comment: Chrome 48 seems not to have the shield icon anymore.

Comment: @kwill When I click on the shield icon and choose to run unsafe scripts, that still does not fix the issue. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: See January 5th, 2016 post from "che" below.

Comment: This does not appear to work in Chrome 55, I have posted a question regarding this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498423/how-to-get-latest-chrome-version-55-to-allow-mixed-content

Comment: No icon in Chrome 59

Comment: Worked. But I can't find how to disable 'run insecure content'. You can enable it, but you can't disable it. `Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)`

Comment: No longer a viable answer.  Chrome has removed the shield icon.

Comment: I got `Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and I got the shield icon. Might be because I'm redirecting `https` request to `http://localhost`.

Comment: Works for me as well on `Version 64.0.3282.167`, and you just have to close the tab to disable it

Comment: Confirmed on 75.x

Comment: Working on Version 86.0.4240.75, but I also had to clear the cookies for this site (Found at the top of the site settings page)

Comment: still valid answer, just click where the Shield icon used to be, the list of options is just alot larger but the option is still there.

Comment: Even when insecure content is allowed, it still blocks mixed content.

Comment: I was able to get to the site settings by clicking on the lock to the right of the address bar

Comment: Allowing insecure content does not prevent blocking "mixed content". Mixed content is different than insecure

Comment: @KristiJorgji The "Allow insecure content" site setting in Chrome as of Version 116.0.5845.180 _does_ unblock "mixed content" defined as HTTP content delivered on an HTTPS page.  Linguistically they appear to be different, but that's just how Chrome is labeling the setting to enable mixed content.  Test it for yourself at https://www.bennish.net/mixed-content.html

Answer (score 52):

In Windows open the Run window  (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --allow-running-insecure-content
```

In OS-X `Terminal.app` run the following command <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-running-insecure-content
```

*`Note:` You seem to be able to add the argument `--allow-running-insecure-content` to bypass this for development.  But its not a recommended solution.*

Answer (score 38):

The shield icon that is being mentioned was not in the sidebar for me either, however I solved it doing the following:

Find the shield icon located in the far right of the URL input bar,

[image]

Once clicked, the following popup should appear wherein you can click *Load unsafe scripts*,

[image]

That should result in a page refresh and the scripts should start working. What used to be an error,

[image]

is now merely a warning,

[image]

**OS:** Windows 10

**Chrome Version:** 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

---

**Edit #1**

On version 66.0.3359.117, the shield icon is still available:

[image]

Notice how the popup design has changed, so this *is* Chrome on version 66.0.3359.117.

**Note:** The shield icon will only appear when you try to load insecure content (content from `http`) while on `https`.

Comment: @Keynes The above simply mitigates the effects temporarily. If you wanted to solve it completely, ensure that all your outgoing requests are going to a secured (`https`) server instead of `http`.

Comment: I'm not able see the shield icon, Chrome version: 66.0.3359.117

Comment: @Venkat it is still available for me. I've just updated to the latest version. Please see **Edit #1**.

Answer (score 10):

On OSX using the current Chrome build (2/20/2020, 79.0.3945.130), you can:

Click on the 'i' info icon on the left side of address bar.

Click `Site Settings`

Scroll down to `Insecure content`

Change it from `Blocked (Default)` to `Allow`

Reload the page and try your action again.

Comment: Works in Google Chrome too

Comment: @codemirror thanks, sorry, i had a typo in my original post. I meant, OSX using Chrome

Comment: On chrome, it still blocks mixed content even after doing this.

Answer (score 8):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" " --allow-running-insecure-content"

Comment: I think this doesn’t work any longer

Answer (score 7):

running the following command helps me running https web-page, with iframe which has ws (unsecured) connection

chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\temp-chrome --disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content

Comment: I found I had to use these two settings to get my extension working in developer mode using Mixed Content. I have a detailed explanation here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498423/how-to-get-latest-chrome-version-55-to-allow-mixed-content

Comment: I tried `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --allow-running-insecure-content` and that did not work for me.  And I tried with `--disable-web-security`.  The **key** was `--user-data-dir`

Answer (score 6):

Another solution which is permanent in nature between sessions without requiring you to run a specific command when opening chrome is as follows:

1. Open a Chrome window
2. In the URL bar enter Chrome://net-internals
3. Click on "Domain Security Policy" in the side-bar
4. Add the domain name which you want to always be able to access in http form into the "Add HSTS/PKP domain" section

Comment: I tried this, it does not work.  HSTS/PKP settings are to tell the browser to request HTTPS from the server even if the requested URL says http: or doesn't say any protocol at all.  But the server is expected to support HTTPS, which is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 4):

On OSX the following works from the command line:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-running-insecure-content
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to go to Chrome Flags and enter the origin that you want to unblock

```
chrome://flags/
```

Search:

> Insecure origins treated as secure

**Enter** Domain or IP address with port, and **choose** Enabled

For example:

```
http://192.168.68.102:3000
```

**Relaunch chrome**

Comment: This is the only one that works for me now (November 2023)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 46 and newer should be showing mixed content without any warning, just without the green lock in address bar.

Source: [Simplifying the Page Security Icon in Chrome](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com.au/2015/10/simplifying-page-security-icon-in-chrome.html) at Google Online Security Blog.

Comment: To clarify it isn't necessarily showing the content automatically, it simply isn't signaling with a triangular warning on the https:// portion of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cors anywhere for testing purposes. But its note recommend for production environments.

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

something like: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://yourdomain.com/api

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.