# ajax call to localhost from site loaded over https fails in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

-------------------- UPDATE 2 ------------------------

I see now that what I am trying to accomplish is not possible with chrome. But I am still curios, why is the policy set stricter with chrome than for example Firefox? Or is it perhaps that firefox doesn't actually make the call either, but javascript-wise it deems the call failed instead of all together blocked?

---------------- UPDATE 1 ----------------------

The issue indeed seems to be regarding calling http from https-site, this error is produced in the chrome console:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://login.mysite.com/mp/quickstore1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost/biztv_local/video/video_check.php?video=253d01cb490c1cbaaa2b7dc031eaa9f5.mov&fullscreen=on'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Then the question is why Firefox allows it, and whether there is a way to make chrome allow it. It has indeed worked fine until just a few months ago.

---

Original question:

I have some jQuery making an ajax call to http (site making the call is loaded over https).

Moreover, the call from my https site is to a script on the localhost on the clients machine, but the file starts with the

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

So that's fine. Peculiar setup you might say but the client is actually a mediaplayer.

It has always worked fine before, and still works fine in firefox, but since about two months back it isn't working in chrome.

Has there been a revision to policies in chrome regarding this type of call? Or is there an error in my code below that firefox manages to parse but chrome doesn't?

The error only occurs when the file is NOT present on the localhost (ie if a regular web user goes to this site with their own browser, naturally they won't have the file on their localhost, most won't even have a localhost) so one theory might be that since the file isn't there, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is never encountered and therefore the call in its entirety is deemed insecure or not allowed by chrome, therefore it is never completed?

If so, is there an event handler I can attach to my jQuery.ajax method to catch that outcome instead? As of now, complete is never run if the file on localhost isn't there.

```
before : function( self ) {

    var myself = this;

    var data = self.slides[self.nextSlide-1].data;

    var html = myself.getHtml(data);
    $('#module_'+self.moduleId+'-slide_'+self.slideToCreate).html(html);


    //This is the fullscreen-always version of the video template
    var fullscreen = 'on';

    //console.log('runnin beforeSlide method for a video template');
    var videoCallStringBase = "http://localhost/biztv_local/video/video_check.php?"; //to call mediaplayers localhost
    var videoContent='video='+data['filename_machine']+'&fullscreen='+fullscreen;
    var videoCallString = videoCallStringBase + videoContent;

    //TODO: works when file video_check.php is found, but if it isn't, it will wait for a video to play. It should skip then as well...
    //UPDATE: Isn't this fixed already? Debug once env. is set up

    console.log('checking for '+videoCallString);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:    videoCallString,
        success: function(result) {
            //...if it isn't, we can't playback the video so skip next slide
            if (result != 1) {
                console.log('found no video_check on localhost so skip slide '+self.nextSlide);
                self.skip();                
            }
            else {
                //success, proceed as normal
                self.beforeComplete();
            }
        }, 
        complete: function(xhr, data) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                //we could not find the check-video file on localhost so skip next slide
                console.log('found no video_check on localhost so skip slide '+self.nextSlide);
                self.skip();                        
            }
            else {
                //success, proceed as normal
                self.beforeComplete();
            }
        }, //above would cause a double-slide-skip, I think. Removed for now, that should be trapped by the fail clause anyways.
        async: true
    });
```

Comment: Can't you just change `videoCallStringBase = "http://localhost...` to use `https`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content sheds some light on my question...

Comment: @alan0xd7 wouldn't that require a cert. on the localhost?

Comment: For development you can just use a self signed cert.

Comment: Ok, but the point was to have this request not blocked when a normal user accesses the site. I see now that that is not possible, I will have to do a workaround somehow. I also see that my case is confusing =) a very specialized implementation

Comment: Any news on how you solved this? I have a similar problem where I need to get a file from http://localhost:<someport> from a webapp served via https.

Comment: @alan0xd7 it seems ridiculous to even need https for localhost, although there is a trick to getting a browser recognized cert that works with localhost