# How to catch Mixed Content error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, https, mixed-content

I have a chrome Extension which parse web pages, and when I start to parse the **"http"** page which has **"https"** in links on this page I have a mixed content errors. Or if I scan **"https"** page which contains **"http"** links, I have the same problem.
Previous I've fixed this issue by redirecting from **HTTPS** to **HTTP**, but know the website which I crawle use both of **http** and **https** URLs, and some pages can't redirect to HTTP.
I've searched about 3 days how to solve this, but didn't find anything which will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [security feature](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox) to protect user, which is enable by default. You have to change some hidden config of browsers.

[For chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27395465/2218838),

> You seem to be able to add the argument --allow-running-insecure-content to bypass.

[For firefox](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-mixed-content-firefox),

> To disable mixed content warnings in Firefox on your Windows 8, open Firefox, enter **about:config** into address bar and hit Enter.
>
> Using the search box, search for a setting called **security.mixed_content.block_active_content**.
>
> Once you have found it, double-click on it. Its value will automatically change from True to False.

Comment: The problem is this extension using a lot of people around the world and I can't tell them to do this. I need to do something like this with javascript, will google it, or if you know how to do something like this with javascript I will grateful to you

Comment: @jason No, we can't. It's a security feature, which means developer can not bypass it.

Comment: I saw how one extension before running make page not as serure, like this: before - http://prntscr.com/be8syo and after: http://prntscr.com/be8t29