# Calling external HTTP api from HTTPS django+angular server on AWS

Tags: django, angular, api, http, proxy

Is this possible?
I am building a ecommerce site that requires calling external api service built on HTTP. 
My site is built on AWS EBS, with django(backend) and angular2(frontend).
If I try to call the HTTP api from angular side, mixed-contents errors pops up, which is apparently the chrome browser blocking the call.

Is there a way to do this? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486282/using-http-api-from-https-page) regarding proxy, but because I'm a newbie, I don't really get how to I can proxy the call with django or angular. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is serving the content over HTTPS, its a must to access other resources also through HTTPS to solve the mixed content issue. The best way to approach is to use a proxy. For that you can either setup a proxy manually using EC2 or using a managed service like [AWS CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) or [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) depending on the nature of the resources you access.

If its a REST API use API Gateway and if its more of content (JS, CSS, HTML and other files & etc.) use CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll look into using AWS API Gateway.