# Not able link javascript from subdomain

Tags: javascript

I am using a sub domain to reduce size of website . i just want to link the script from sub domain. Scripts work perfectly well while linked with the same domain, but it is not working while linked with the sub domain. for example

my domain = https://www.test.com

sub domain = http://abc.test.com

and i am using =

```
 <script src= "http://abc.test.com/js/combodate.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: "not working" is a poor problem statement. What does the Console in your browser's developer tools say? What does the Network tab show — e.g. is the script loading with a 200 OK response — ?

Comment: `http://abc.test.com/js/combodate.js` redirects to an HTML document. Is that your real URL? If not, use `example.com`, that domain is provided specifically for giving examples.

Comment: @Quentin hi .. there is no error on console , or when i click on the link in view page source , it shows me the script . but it is not working ...

Comment: @PunitGajjar i already mentioned .. i am not getting any error ...

Comment: @Nits — and the Network tab says what?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is pretty obvious from what I can see:

Your main website url uses `https://` but your script subdomain uses `http://`, and as modern browsers have a fully-safe-domain policy currently (no different protocols for loading resources, all should be on the same protocol as the main domain, aka the one you accessed the website through), your subdomain should also use `https://` or your main domain should use `http://`.

As stated on [MDN's page about mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) most browsers only let `mixed passive/display content`(`<img>`, `<audio>`, `<video>` and `<object>(subresources)`) load through mixed content, but rather `<script>`, `<link>`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `<iframe>`, `in-css url()` and `<object>(data attribute)` are `active content` and as such, could be subject to a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), therefore browsers do not allow loading of active content in a mixed environment (tl;dr use https for both js and your main website or http both js and main website).

It is also worth to note that the inverse (resources on `https://` and main page on `http://`) works as expected because the https connection to the resource is not subject to man in the middle attacks and since the page is on `http://` browsers do not consider it a "security critical area" so you are able to load content through both `http://` and `https://`

Comment: An answer to his question is JSONP in my opinion. Not a problems with protocol.

Comment: @dawidr Try to use `http://` and `https://` with chrome and it'll give out a mixed content warning and not load the Js on the unsecure domain.

Comment: @GGG — The OP says there is no error on the console though.

Comment: It's not an error but rather a warning. [Chrome silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content) kills [of mixed content](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OrwppKWbKnc) and [so does firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=how-does-content-isnt-secure-affect-my-safety)

Comment: @GGG yeah . i think you got me correct . is there any solution to go with the same http subdomain,

Comment: @GGG or there is any way to link with the http sub domain to https subdomain... Thanks

Comment: @Nits There's no way unless you make your subdomain also be https (or the main domain be http) as browsers will block the content by any means possible unless you disable that security option (but in production that wouldn't be viable, imagine a website with a popup saying: "please disable X security option so our website can work"...).

Answer (score -3):

Try adding the following to your html page:

```
<script src="http://abc.test.com/js/combodate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is important to:

1. Make sure you use the `src` attribute
2. Make sure you open *and* close the `<script></script>` tag

Comment: There is no value in this answer at all.