# Team Foundation Servcices (TFS) Diff tool not working

Tags: azure-devops

Our team is migrating our tfs build to vNext. There is a new capability that automatically version controls the build definitions, which can be seen in the History Tab (see below). I am trying to view differences between versions of the build definition using the "Diff tool". I keep getting a mixed content error when trying to look at the differences between build definitions. I tried in IE and Chrome and am getting the same error. I also allowed mixed content in IE with no luck. Anyone has a workaround? Thanks. [image: TFS Build Screenshot - History Tab]

Comment: I can’t reproduce this issue (My TFS version 14.102.25423.0), all requests via HTTPS protocol, such as VSS.Controls.css. What’s the detail version of TFS?

Comment: Version 14.95.25122.0

Comment: Does the new team project has the same issue? Could you upgrade your TFS?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade TFS. I have no control over that part of the infrastructure.

Comment: What's the detail of your TFS? How do you configure SSL (https) with your TFS? Could you access through Http protocol?

Comment: Did you try launching Chrome with mixed content allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content?