# Using jQuery to load contents from a HTTP page onto a HTTPS page

Tags: jquery, http, https

I am using a Chrome extension to display contents from a http website on a https website using the code below:

```
$("#div").html('<object data="http://example.com/"');
```

However I'm receiving this error due to mixing http and https:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://website.com' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure plugin resource
>   'http://example.com/'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can I overcome this? The http website cannot be loaded with https.

*Note: I have to use Javascript/jQuery as I am using the code in a Chrome extension.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content)

Comment: basically you can't. It's a Security Concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can kludge it by writing a proxy script (which can reside anywhere) that can be accessed externally via HTTPS, and which retrieves the requested URL behind the scenes via HTTP.

Your extension would request:

```
$("#div").html('<object data="https://your-proxy-server.com/your-script">');
```