# How to get Latest Chrome (Version 55) to allow mixed content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mixed-content

I have a chrome extension that communicates using HTTP in development and HTTPS in production.

I run it from webpages that use HTTPS.

When I use this extension in my development mode I get the following error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://somesite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://david-sniper.local:3001/api/end-point'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

In the past I have been able to resolve this error by going reading this post [how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content)

There are two solutiions in this post.

1. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --allow-running-insecure-content
2. In the address bar at the right end should be a 'shield' icon, you can click on that to run insecure content.

I have never had success with the first solution, but the second solution where you click on the 'shield' icon was working up until a few weeks ago.

I'm now on Chrome 55 and there is NO Shield option to click on, so I'm wondering how to get mixed content working in developer mode?

[image]

Comment: While it is not what you are asking, the right answer is that you make your development environment as near-identical to your production environment as possible. In other words, use HTTPS for both. Having your development environment, or at least your development *testing* environment, be different than your production environment is just asking for problems when you move code from development into production, which is really *not* when you want to be finding problems.

Comment: The messages at `console` are warnings, not errors, yes?

Comment: The actual requests are blocked, e.g. the call to jora-list  is not being executed, so while the messages are warnings, the effect is a broken code.

Comment: there is a chrome startup parameter to disable all security. look into it.

Answer (score 13):

Following a tip by Zig Mandel, I used command line parameters to run Chrome without security.

I created a folder called `c:\_chrome_data` and I unpacked my developer extension into chrome extensions and I used this command line.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-running-insecure-content --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:\_chrome_data
```

Click the Shield, I noticed that the shield is not available in Version 55 of chrome anymore unless you have the settings listed in the command line included.

[image]

**Working Extension**

[image]