# Modifying ASP.NET app to run over HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, port

Just to preface this: I know that this is a horrible idea, but just trust me here. If I was in any other position I would avoid doing this.

I have an application built in Visual Studio that uses IIS on HTTPS port 44300. I am replacing some `HTTPS` API requests with others that use `HTTP`. Chrome prevents these requests with mixed content errors. I have looked at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content) that mention the same thing and all come up with hacky answers that should never be used in production.

Since there is no chance that I can get the API to switch to `HTTPS`, I am looking to modify my app to run on `HTTP`.

My attempt at doing this is modifying the project's properties. (Project -> Properties -> Web -> Servers).
[image: Editing the project]

You can see that I have the project URL set to use `HTTPS`

When I change that url to be `http://localhost:44300` the application starts me at `https://localhost/` even though that's not the config, and tells me that localhost can't be reached. No big deal, I manually change the URL to be `http://localhost:44300` and it sends me back to `https://localhost/`. When I leave out the port and just manually enter `http://localhost` I get a 404 page.

I have also tried setting the port to `80` in the Project properties page. I just get automatically redirected to `https://localhost` when I delete the `S`.

The app is built using ASP.NET.

Is there some obvious issue that I'm not seeing with IIS and the port? Or is this an issue with the way that my app is built? In which case, this is a bad question.

Comment: Do you also have the normal IIS installed? It might be redirecting to https://localhost

Comment: Following [these steps](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) _in reverse_ may help

Comment: @Mitta I believe it came installed with my computer. I can try reinstalling it.

Comment: @fstylermiller you can check this in the "Windows features" panel. There must be a "Internet Information Services" node. See if this is checked, if it is, IIS is installed. In that case see if this IIS might be doing the redirect as mentioned before.

Comment: @Mitta funny enough, it is there, but not checked.

Comment: Since you are using IISExpress, did you check applicationhost.config file under `.vs\Config` folder? Normally this folder is hidden folder and is located where solution file resides.

Comment: @PankajKapare I did check that file, no mention of http or https :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with the way that my app was configured.

This line was the culprit:

```
filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if your Web.config includes the following lines

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://localhost" />
```

or

UrlRewrite configuration

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
```

It might also have to do with HTST and Chrome in case you use Chrome. See this answer

[Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)

Comment: Web.config does not have either of those, and that answer did not solve the problem. Thank you for the effort, though.