# How to enable mixed content (insecure mode) in browsers (Chrome, Opera, FF) for local development at Mac OS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox

I simply tried almost all known ways to enable mixed content in browsers. Nothing works on Mac.
This [link](https://pearsonnacommunity.force.com/support/s/article/How-to-display-mixed-content-with-Google-Chrome-Internet-Explorer-or-Firefox-1408394589290) provides some solutions that aren't working for me.

Also i tried `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content` without positive result. Do you have any thoughts how to make it work at Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this command `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/tempchrome --allow-running-insecure-content --incognito &`

It works fine.

Comment: Looking for something that will allow mixed content chrome 2019 for macos? This worked for me. Spawns a new incognito window that will load http from https.