# Angular 5 Mixed Blocked Content

Tags: angular, heroku, xmlhttprequest, angular5, angular-httpclient

I have deployed an Angular 5 application to Heroku **(HTTPS site)** that retrieves json data **(HTTP request endpoint)** from a third party.

I get the following Mixed Content blocked error:

[image: ERROR]

NOTE: The HTTP request endpoint can't be changed to HTTPS.

This is my call to the request endpoint:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

private httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':  'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, OPTIONS',
  'Content-Type':  'application/json'
})


};
  this.http.get<Skater[]>(this.skaterServiceUrl, this.httpOptions);
```

How can I make the request from an **HTTPS** site to a **HTTP** request endpoint?

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try by adding this. <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *">

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna thanks for the response. I added the following per your suggestion: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"> . Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Any other ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find a convenient way to serve up mixed content to a broad array of users/browsers. I think `img`s and other tags will display, but xmlHttpRequest calls will not.

There used to be a shield icon in Chrome that you could click to display mixed content – see [How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content). There are also answers there about configuring Chrome to display mixed content, but that's not something you'd expect each user to do.

I'd recommend you simply **proxy the request** via this Heroku server. Not sure what language you're running on the server, but can you just GET `/some-path` and then have a function run at that path that performs the HTTP request? I've done this before and found it very useful.