# Code can run in XAMPP server but cannot run in 000webhost.com

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

```js
function valform()
{
 var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
 var h2 = document.getElementById("height1").value;
 var w2 = document.getElementById("weight1").value;
 var r2 = document.getElementById("txtresult").value;
 
 if( name == ""  || h2 == "" || w2 == "" || r2 == "" )
 {
  alert("Please fill in the blank(s) first");
  return false;
 }
 if(!($('input[type=radio]:checked').size() == 12))
 {
  alert("You must answer all the questions");
  return false;
 }
}
```

So, basically the code above cannot run in 000webhost.com but can run with XAMPP server. If I click submit when all the radio buttons do not checked, it supposed to show the alert but it just go to another page. I checked all the syntax are correct and still not working. So I wonder why? 
The link: https://cancertool123.000webhostapp.com/Questionnaire%20(Colon%20Cancer).php

Some explanations will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see in the Console (press F12 in your website), there is an error:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://cancertool123.000webhostapp.com/Questionnaire%20(Colon%20Cancer).php'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The problem is you are loading a http file within a https site.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! You saved my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading jquery file from **http** and your website is working on **https** so change it to this

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

it will work

Comment: Appreciated! That's why it couldn't work lol. Anyway, thank you so much ;)