# Updating a webpage to include a iframe being blocked but initial loading works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, https

If I add the following HTML to a webpage it renders just fine:

```
<iframe src="http://website.com" id="#iFrameContainer"style="position:fixed; top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width: 100%; border: none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow: hidden; z-index:999999; height: 100%;">');
```

However if I do the following jQuery:

```
$('#iFrameUpdate').replaceWith('<iframe src="http://website.com" id="#iFrameContainer"style="position:fixed; top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width: 100%; border: none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow: hidden; z-index:999999; height: 100%;">');
```

Same goes for `.html()`, `.innerHTML()`... etc

It fails... throwing:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mainwebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://website.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I can't get HTTPS on the iframe source as I don't control that server fully.

Any ideas how to bypass this?

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow you to load HTTP resources when it originates from javascript, and produces a warning if it originates from the page request. So unless you host your site on HTTP or reload the page with the correct URL, I don't think there is anything you can do.

Comment: @dotconnor there's no way to authorise the non-HTTPS request via some sort of two way key system?

Comment: the only way I know how to is to have the client allow it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because someone has answered in comments. :(