# How to reenable Mixed Content Blocking in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

By Default, Chrome blocks mixed content. This can be circumvented as per [How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content).

Now I reconfigured my website to no longer need mixed content to be allowed. How do I reenable it? The page still shows as "insecure" next to the URL because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting chrome will do the trick. Use Ctrl+Shift+T to reopen all tabs. Keep in mind that data entered into forms may be lost.