# Frontend http and backend https causes problems in the smartphone

Tags: docker, http, https, graphql, angular9

I am developing a web app with which it should be possible to use the sensor data in the smartphone.
The WebApp is developed with Angular and the backend is nodejs, apollo, prisma, graphql.

The database (mysql) is in a Docker container.

In order to be able to use the sensor data, the server must be hosted using https. But this is exactly the problem.

google chrome gives me an error message that mixed content is blocked. I assume that it is because the database is accessible via http and the webapp via https.

is there a possibility to do the whole thing in the form or does the db server also have to use an HTTPS protocol? If so, how should this be done?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Τhe `"mix content"` message is not related to the database connection but to the fact that the web app is `http` and the sensor server is `https`. See here how you can enable the mixed content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content

Comment: 0


You can safely assume that I mean the server that has a connection to the DB. But unfortunately that doesn't help me either, because I need more help as I can do with the smartphone browser (chrome)