# how to send a post request through http in website that uses https?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, https, xmlhttprequest

I am creating a chrome extension that need to send post request to a server over normal http but this causes a mixed content error and browser don't process the request when I am in a website that user Https.

**error message:**

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.se:8080/v1/check'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
    var settings = {
  "url": "http://example.se:8080/v1/check",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "postman-token": "e7705111-e7d7-0284-e4cd-56115243e076",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"langCode":"pt-rr","text":"Por favor, leia as regrs. Meu nom é Nicolas. bowré o qunto maor pabn dks do."}),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Why does it need to be sent over HTTP? Do you have access to the webserver? Upgrading to HTTPS is really the solution here.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, that's why I am trying to find a way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not recommendable** to use **mix-content**, You should use **HTTPS**.

But if you want to bypass it for **Development Purpose**, You can allow it in **site settings**.

*Refer this question*
[How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content)