# .NET Core Swagger UI Mix Content Restriction (Http Vs Https)

Tags: .net, https, swagger, kestrel

Swagger UI for .NET Core currently has a very strict mix content request block feature. If the server is receiving HTTP content when user is requesting over HTTPS content, Javascript in UI will block the content. I however really need it to be less restrictive. I'm hosting Kestrel API over http that only allow local access and have Apache proxy bind to 443 that calls localhost Kestrel. I cannot do anything with Kestrel where I cannot bind any certificate so I can run HTTPS over Kestrel. Is there anyway to allow this?

Swagger V. 5.6.2
[Client] -- HTTPS --> [Apache] -- proxy local host HTTP -> [Kestrel]

This use to work on version 5.5.1

Comment: Mixed content is blocked by browser, not by Swagger UI. If you use Chrome, see [How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18321032/113116)

Comment: But I saw the error reported from js file and the previous version was working on the same browser config. Any thought?