# Why HTML 5 cannot play stream when using HTTPS?

Tags: html, http, audio, https

I have internet radio stream on the address:
http://hyades.shoutca.st:8155/stream
Also, I have web page radiolivade.com, and in the index.html is the following line which plays the internet radio stream

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="http://hyades.shoutca.st:8155/stream>"
</audio>
```

When call http://radiolivade.com from a browser, stream music works.But, when call https://radiolivade.com, stream doesn't works, and play control is unavailable.
How to fix this problem?
I have plan to redirect all traffics to the https://radiolivade.com, but stream https://hyades.shoutca.st:8155/stream does not exists, only http://

Best regards,

Comment: The HTML you show is invalid. You enclosed the closing `>` within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your request to `HTTPS` from `HTTP` is blocked because of [Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) policy. Modern browsers block by default such requests.

You verify that with tools like:

- https://www.missingpadlock.com/
- https://www.whynopadlock.com/
- https://httpschecker.net/

You bypass that and disable the error on your browser temporarily, just Google how to disable Mixed Content for your browser (for Chrome [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434461/5078746)). But for your users, you have to upgrade to HTTPS if you want to consume these resources. That's easier and safer for you and your users than using a proxy between your HTTP website and HTTPS resource.

You opt for free TLS certificates with [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) while you get a paid one.

See more:

- [Mixed Content on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)
- [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)
- [What is Mixed Content](https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/)

Comment: Or is it because he enclosed the closing `>` within the quote marks?