# How can I consume and HTTP API in my HTTPS website

Tags: django, http, deployment, https

I built the frontend of my website using React, and it is hosted on netlify. Here is an example of a call I make to my API.

```
fetch(`http://blabla.com/all/`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        }
        ).then((data) => {
            let informations = data.restaurant;
            // do stuff with data
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

This site is hosted on an https domain, provided by netfily. Then, my backend is a Django app, built with Docker compose and hosted on digital ocean droplets, that serves via HTTP. But each time I can the API with the site, it returns that

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure
 resource 'http:...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served
 over HTTPS.
```

How can I fix this? Is there anything that can be done on the frontend to allow it?

Otherwise, how do I put the HTTPS stuff on digital ocean droplets and django? Because I spent almost three hours trying to figure it out, without being able to do so.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern browsers block [`Mixed Content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content), you can disable this on your browser temporarily if you want to debug or test your website.

However, it is recommended to have HTTPS everyhwere, using solutions like Certbot from [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) might be a good start.

Please have a look at:

- [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)
- [How to get Chrome to allow mixed content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content/24434461#24434461)

---

You can also use tools like these to check if you still have this issue:

- https://www.missingpadlock.com/
- https://www.whynopadlock.com/
- https://httpschecker.net/