# node js https net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, ssl, socket.io

I implemented following code to make node js runs on https

```
const https = require('https');
const options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('apache key file path.key', "UTF-8"),
        crt: fs.readFileSync('apache crt file path.crt', "UTF-8")

}
const httpsvr = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
       res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
       res.end('TEST HTTPS\n');
});

const io = require('socket.io')(httpsvr);

httpsvr.listen(8443);

io.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log('connect error ' + err.message );
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('TestNodeEvent', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     console.log('io8443 connected');
   });
});`
```

This runs https server.But client side can't make socket.io connection.Therefore broadcasting not                           happening

```
socket = io('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8443');
socket.on('testupdate', function (data) `
```

I try to send page refresh signal to other users and socket io not connecting properly.
I get following errors from browsers

```
Chrome - net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Firefox -
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at      https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8443/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfUXCGt. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

`

```
Node JS version  - v14.21.3
socket.io        - 4.2.0
socket.io-client - 4.2.0
```

I want to make page refresh happening on other users while one use select particular option that should go from other users

This is what i get when do culr and openssl in back end

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139917842872128:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 289 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Please provide the output  you get on the server side, i.e. from your nodejs

Comment: Thanks all.I am not getting any console.log message when I try using my server certificates apache i get following error in node.log

Comment: my node.log not getting any logs when I use apache key and cert files i get this error Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name: :no start line reason: 'no start line', code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'

Comment: The line means that your certificate and/or key are in the wrong format.  Thus they cannot be loaded and thus HTTPS cannot be done with these. This is a duplicate of other questions with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Apache or nginx on ubuntu you should modify your code to

```js
const https = require('https');
```

and for HTTPS Server use **CERTBOT**
first try installing certbot and after successfully install Run this Command if you are using apache

```js
sudo certbot --apache
```

or if you are using nginx

```js
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Comment: I cannot see how this answers the question.

Comment: Sorry If You Didn't Get The Answer Actually I Mean To Say If You Are Creating HTTPS Server then You also need to add and ssl using Certbot then you can access it over HTTPS generally Cross Origin Request Error Occurs When You Request On HTTP From a HTTPS server actually For Testing Purpose You can disable security check from your browser

Comment: Hi @AnantKumar I cant send http request because chrome doesn't allow it socket = io('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8443'); This worked fine with http but when i implement https all broke I can see node js requests coming to linux server but no logs

Comment: @AnantKumar: The OP is not using a reverse proxy here (just check the port) - so anything about apache and nginx makes no sense. So OP also seems to have already got its certificates - so anything about certbot is irrelevant here too.

Comment: Hi All when i use ps -ef|grep node root        1378       1  0 Aug19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mcelog --ignorenodev --daemon --foreground
root     3880627       1  3 15:10 ?        00:00:42 /usr/bin/node /usr/wasp11/source/prod/node/node_start.js
root     3901301 3407795  0 15:31 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto node

Comment: I am running two porst 8080 and 8443 both are not working properlly my server certificate is okay when i use following java script code

Comment: node twonode.js
(node:3903937) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
301
{
  date: 'Mon, 04 Sep 2023 05:34:52 GMT',
  server: 'Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_fcgid/2.3.9',
  location: 'https://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx/',
  'content-length': '242',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
}

Comment: @SteffenUllrich When I use my key and crt files in apache config I cant turn on node js server so I used self signed and export server certificates but those are not valid in chrome

Comment: https.get('https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/',
res => {

     ciphers: 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0';
     console.log(res.statusCode);
     console.log(res.headers);
})
I get following error Error: write EPROTO 139856252049280:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1563:SSL alert number 40
 errno: -71,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'

Comment: Yeah For Instance If You Want Your response success just turn off insecure content setting from your browser here is how can you turn off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content