# How can I disable the mixed content for the selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, mixed-content

I have a website that I am doing automation testing using Selenium web driver, Java.
The site has mixed content problem as it uses both HTTP and HTTPS.
Now before initializing ChromeDriver, I want to disable the mixed content.
can someone be of an assistance?

FYI: I have successfully disabled it on firefox geckodriver as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile=new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxprofile.setPreference("security.mixed_content.block_active_content",false);
firefoxprofile.setPreference("security.mixed_content.block_display_content",false);
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxprofile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

can I do the same while using ChromeDriver?

Comment: Seems duplicated or similar to: [how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content). That thread could help you.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I am able to resolve it using just a single line of code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content"); //This resolved mixed content
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```